# SEO Friendly Images for TimThumb

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website that uses [TimThumb](https://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/) and want to replace:

`https://example.com/wp-content/tools/TimThumb.php?src=/wp-content/uploads/property-images/140211/140211__3.jpg&w=800&h=800&zc=3`

with:

`https://example.com/zc3/800/800/wp-content/uploads/property-images/140211/140211__3.jpg`

This will enable SEO friendly images.

**How would I edit the TimThumb PHP file (`TimThumb.php`) and/or `.htaccess` file to make this happen?**

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by adding the following code to the top of my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN TimThumb rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule images/zc([0-9]?)/([0-9]{1,4})/([0-9]{1,4})(.*)$ wp-content/tools/TimThumb.php?src=$4&w=$2&h=$3&zc=$1 [NE]
</IfModule>
# END TimThumb rewrite
```